# How to make two-way binding on Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to create custom input, so I created this component:

`MyInputComponent.razor`:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" @bind="BindingValue" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string BindingValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then the usage:

```
<EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
    <MyInputComponent BindingValue="model.Name" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    User model = new User() { Name = "My Name" };

    private void Submit()
    {
       // here I found model.Name = null;
   }
}
```

When I debug `MyInputComponent`, I found the value as I have entered. But when I submit the form, the value is null.

What is missing?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

## Quick answer

Quoting [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding):

> **Component parameters**
>
> Binding recognizes component parameters, where @bind-{property} can bind a property value across components.

For your page:

```
<EditForm Model="model" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
    <MyInputComponent @bind-BindingValue="model.Name" />
</EditForm>
```

The child component `MyInputComponent`:

```
<div>
  <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="@BindingValue" />
</div>

@code {

    private string _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string BindingValue
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value == value ) return;
            _value = value;
            BindingValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }   

}
```

**Notice**

- You should to raise binding changes from children component through `EventCallback<string> BindingValueChanged`.
- I chose `BindingValue` and `BindingValueChanged` as identifiers, but, you can use just `Value` and `ValueChanged`. Then will be: `<MyInputComponent @bind-Value="model.Name" />`

[Try it at BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ytf1uobj).

*(Edited 2022) Full documented now at: [Binding with component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-with-component-parameters)*

**Edited: See Option 2 below for a clean solution:**

---

## Your control inside an EditForm

If you want to put your component inside an EditForm and deal with validations, or take other actions using the onchange event, you should to raise `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged`. You have 2 options to do it.

### Option 1: Raising from EditContext

You can get `EditContext` from `CascadeParameter` and invoke `NotifyFieldChanged` by hand:

```
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext EditContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region bindedValue
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    private string _value { set; get; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;
            _value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            var fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
            EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);

        }
    }
```

### Option 2 (recomended): Through inheritance from InputBase

You can inherit from `InputBase<string>` and just implement `TryParseValueFromString`. `InputBase` will do the work for you,When you inherit from [`InputBase`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs) you have `Value`, `ValueChanged`, `EditContext`, etc.

```
protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
{
    result = value ?? "";
    validationErrorMessage = null;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: dani, if you choose to provide a solution using the built-in InputText Component, then why not suggest to inherit from the class the InputText Component itself derives. It's simpler and requires less code, and allow you to control the rendering of the input Html tag as you please, as for instance, creating a custom component for passwords. Still better, why not suggest the OP to use the InputText Component directly in the EditForm...good day.

Comment: @Issac, because the question is **How to make two-way binding on Blazor component**

Comment: That is true...but it is not a general question on how to do it without a context: you have to take into consideration the code the user employs, as for instance, MyInputComponent component uses the Html input tag. Your solution does not use it. Instead you use the built-in TextInput component, thus my comment suggests that if you go this way, then use the built-in components directly.

Comment: Thanks dani, this got me over an issue with binding custom components! @Isaac, I would love to see an alternative answer with your suggestions if you have a chance to post it!

Comment: Is there a way to bind an object instead of only a string or are all child components forced to only have 1 value to be sent back to the parent component?

Comment: @enet I don't think he was suggesting to use the built-in `InputText`. I think he was suggesting to inherit from `InputBase<string>` to roll your own html `<input>` while taking advantage of all the binding, validation and context features.  Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734223/591285

Answer (score 10):

In general the accepted answer is correct and works fine. Only thing to add is the code example uses the default name convention based Events e.g.: `{PropertyName}Changed`.

`[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }`

However **you can override this naming convention** `@bind-{Property}:event="{EventCallbackName}"`

```
<MyInputComponent @bind-BindingValue="model.Name" @bind-BindingValue:event="OnValueChanged"/>

.....

[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 9):

Using Blazor with .NET7 you can do the following:

MyCustomComponent.Razor

```
<input type="text" @bind:get="BindingValue" @bind:set="SetAsync">

@code {


[Parameter]
public string BindingValue { get; set; }    
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }  

async Task SetAsync(string value)=> await BindingValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```

}

Then you can use:

```
<MyCustomComponent @bind-BindingValue="whateverVariable" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It took me a bit to figure out [dani herreras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933827/591285) recommended option so I wanted to provide some clarity for others. I wanted to change all my text inputs to [Bootstrap 5.0 floating labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/#example). Inheriting from `InputBase<string>` gives us a lot to work with. `@CssClass` automatically takes care of applying validation classes and `@CurrentValue` gives us the `@bind-Value` of the component.

**InputComponent.razor**

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input class="form-control @CssClass" id="@Id" @bind="@CurrentValue">
  <label for="@Id">@Label</label>
</div>

 <div class="form-control-validation">
    <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<string>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public string? Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }

    // Note that this is only for implementing CurrentValueAsString
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**SomePage.razor**

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext"  OnValidSubmit=@HandleValidSubmit>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputComponent @bind-Value="person.Name" ValidationFor="@(()=>person.Name)" Label="Name" ></InputComponent>
    <p>Two way binded value: @person.Name</p>

</EditForm>
@code {

    private class ExamplePerson
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private ExamplePerson person { get; set; } = new ExamplePerson();

    private EditContext _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new(person);
        
    }
    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

    }
}
```

Additionally, we can use the Bootstrap 5.0 class names for validation by making the following changes.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _editContext = new(person);
    _editContext.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new BootstrapValidationClassProvider());
}

public class BootstrapValidationClassProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
{
    public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
    {
        if (editContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(editContext));

        bool isValid = !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

        if (editContext.IsModified(fieldIdentifier))
            return isValid ? "is-valid" : "is-invalid";
            
        return isValid ? string.Empty : "is-invalid";
    }
}
```

**Update:** I was quite new to Blazor when I wrote this answer. Instead of inheriting `InputBase<string>` we could use a `typeparam` to do two-way binding on all types.

```
@typeparam TItem
@inherits InputBase<TItem>

.
.
.

[Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<TItem>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;

protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TItem result, out string validationErrorMessage)
{
    result = (TItem)(object)value;
    validationErrorMessage = null;
    return true;
}
```

And then we would call the component like this

```
<InputComponent TItem="int" @bind-Value="person.Age" ValidationFor="@(()=>person.Age)" Label="Age" ></InputComponent>
```