# How to use bind-value and bind-value:event on a custom component Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor, while using inputs,

```
<input bind-value="@InputValue" bind-value:event="oninput"/>
```

This creates a 2 way binding that updates with the oninput event.

I would like to recreate this on a custom component with custom events and custom properties.

**CustomInput.razor**

```
<input value="@Value" oninput="@OnInput" />

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public string Value { get; set; }

   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> OnInput { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to use it this way.

```
<CustomInput bind-Value="@InputValue" bind-Value:event="OnInput" />
```

Is this possible on Blazor right now? If yes, how do I achieve it?

**EDIT:**

For anyone that comes across this, it seems to work as is. I am not sure if the feature was added after the question was asked or if it always worked that way but the code above should work as is. Conventionally, your event name should be *ValueChanged* but if you have a reason to use another event name like in inputs where you have *OnInput* and *OnChange*, then you can use this format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make two-way binding on Blazor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932850/how-to-make-two-way-binding-on-blazor-component)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes Blazor supports 2 way binding. It works with EventCallbacks (which must be triggered) and default uses name convention based Events e.g.: `{PropertyName}Changed`. Also you can override this naming convention `@bind-{Prop}:event="{EventCallbackName}"`. In your code example you are just overriding this default Event name, never triggering it.

**In your code you have 2 issues:**

1. You MUST define bind starting with `@` and inside `""` it is not necessary to use `@` correct for is: `@bind-{PropertyName}="{variable}"`.

Change your code to: `<CustomInput @bind-Value="InputValue" @bind-Value:event="OnInput" />`

2. Already wrote that these events MUST be triggered when actual value has changed. Update your code to:

```
private string _value;
[Parameter] public string Value 
{ 
   get => _value; 
   set
   {
      if(value == _value)
        return;

      _value = value;  
      if(OnInput.HasDelegate)
      {
         OnInput.InvokeAsync(_value);
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this code with `object?` instead of string. When I set the value to an enum value I ended up in an endless loop because the `value == _value` check somehow was not true even if the values seemed to be equal.

So If any your app stops responding check if this is the case for you too and modify the check.

Comment: Just to note, if it must be triggered, it's technically not real 2-way binding. Blazor really has one way binding and triggered binding in the opposite direction (you can't get a property of an external component without triggering, as is said - the binding is conditional).

Comment: You can use naming conventions. So if the event name is {PropertyName}Changed then it is automatically triggered event. But if you give it a different name then you have to trigger it yes. Can be good can be bad it's up to the requirements. You might can apply condition or do other things before event triggered for two way binding...

Comment: Why are you putting logic in the setter? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#component-parameters) says it's disallowed.

Comment: @MC9000 Yes Naming conventions mentioned in the second line.

Comment: @palapapa For me this is working fine. Might be with latest .NET 8 new renderings have side effects. Also if you don't have any Button or other events where you can invoke the Delegate then this is 1 way to do it. Will try it with .NET soon now updating my projects to it. So thanks for the link.

Comment: @Major In [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#binding-with-component-parameters), it seems like the correct way to do this is to use a method that will call `InvokeAsync` instead of using a setter.

Answer (score 17):

The event parameter MUST be called `ValueChanged`

```cs
<input value="@Value" @oninput="ValueChanged" />

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public string Value { get; set; }

   [Parameter]
   public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Read [Binding with component parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-with-component-parameters)

Comment: I think that should be `oninput="@ValueChanged"` ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932850/how-to-make-two-way-binding-on-blazor-component/57933827#57933827

Comment: @daniherrera I flaged the question has duplicate

Comment: @agua, I posted related because I guess it is, but I'm not sure it is exactly the same. For me your answer is right. Do you want I remove the related comment ?

Comment: @daniherrera no, to me the question is a duplicate so I flaged it.

Comment: @aguafrommars although it's been over a year. I thought to mention that the event MUST not be called ValueChanged. I was able to achieve what I intended. It works out of the box.

Comment: Also, it's a related question but not the same. The related question asks about 2-way binding while this asks about 2-way binding with event names that don't follow the naming convention.

Comment: This is totally wrong or outdated. The `@oninput` does not require event parameter name hard coded. See here https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-server/component-interaction-550894

Comment: @RedWei it's from the official doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-with-component-parameters . I don't think it's wrong nor outdated

Comment: My bad, your example is just different from the link I gave.

Comment: Where does it say that it MUST be called ValueChanged?  What if you have 10 controls that need an @oninput event? This can't be true.

Comment: @MC9000 because the property's name is `Value` the event name must be `ValueChanged` , the event name must be `{PropertyName}Changed`  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-with-component-parameters-2

Comment: (ah, thought it was always ValueChanged - doh!). They need to reword this then. When they use "By Convention", as written in that doc, it implies that it's merely a coding convention to make code easier to read, not that the system itself requires it.  So really it's not "By Convention" it's Mandatory.  So, it, wires the event and the param together with that Changed keyword. Got it.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use *@bind* attribute in your input!

```
 <input @bind="myProperty" />
 
 @code{
     private string? myProperty; 
}
```

reference: [ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: The OP is asking about databinding inside a custom object to the outer code. not within the one page/view.