# Capture custom Javascript events in Blazor WASM

Tags: javascript, event-handling, blazor

I am working on a Blazor WASM project where we are using an internal HTML/JS library (a requirement that I can't get around). This library has custom events on it's components that often replace standard events. For example, the `<select>` control has a `valuechanged` event that takes the place of a standard `change` event (the `change` event is no longer emitted for this custom `<select>`). It also has completely custom events, such as a `sort` event on its `<table>` element.

I need to be able to work with these events, but so far have not been able to. I've tried to follow the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-event-arguments, and gotten it set up correctly I believe (because intellisense recognizes the @on____ line), but the code to execute on those events never gets called. I'm not sure if that's because I don't have a `browserEventName`, or for some other reason. I've also tried the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67595043, but again, have not had any success.

Is there a way to wire up listeners/actions to the custom events emitted in the library? The closest I've been able to find on SO to my specific issue is an unanswered question from a few years ago: [How to retrieve Web Component custom event result with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570495/how-to-retrieve-web-component-custom-event-result-with-blazor).

Comment: I never used the new .Net6 feature about custom events and it seems the right way to do it in Blazor. However, the second solution with `JSInterop` and `DotNetObjectReference` should be working: without code we cannot really help. Did you check that the JS function handling the event is triggered?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: These are links to where I capture the Dialog close event on HTML5's dialog element:
https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorDialogs/blob/2485b35783ff27de74f6816f995d26d0ba7721ea/BlazorDialogs/wwwroot/dialogJsInterop.js#L9
https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorDialogs/blob/2485b35783ff27de74f6816f995d26d0ba7721ea/BlazorDialogs/Dialog.razor.cs#L57