# Blazor's InputSelect Component not updating form validations errors on it's value change

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor's InputSelect Component on a field called LocationId.

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please Select Location")]
public int LocationId { get; set; }
```

On my razor component, where form validations are taking place, I am calling a child component like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Location</label>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => StudentData.LocationId)" />
    <SelectCommon RowType="Location" RowData="Locations" @bind-MyPhrase="@StudentData.LocationId">
        <SelectOption>
            <option selected disabled value="0">Choose a Location</option>
        </SelectOption>

        <OptionValue Context="p">
            <option value="@p.Id">@p.City, @p.State</option>
        </OptionValue>
    </SelectCommon>
</div>
```

In the child component there is the `InputSelect` component whose code is:

```
@typeparam RowType

<InputSelect class="form-control" @bind-Value="HandleChange">
    @if (SelectOption != null)
    {
        @SelectOption
    }

    @foreach (RowType item in RowData)
    {
        @OptionValue(item);
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment SelectOption { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<RowType> OptionValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<RowType> RowData { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int MyPhrase { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> MyPhraseChanged { get; set; }

    public int HandleChange
    {
        get { return MyPhrase; }
        set
        {
            MyPhrase = value;
            MyPhraseChanged.InvokeAsync(MyPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

The work of `@bind-Value="HandleChange"` is to create blazor chain binding thing which is working perfectly. The parent component has this attribute `@bind-MyPhrase="@StudentData.LocationId"` which send the value of the model to the child for binding.

The problem is happening when i change the value of the select but the validation messages are not updated. However when I click the button which submits the form the validation messages updates. You can see the below gif which is showning this thing.

[image]

I have also notices that If id do not go with the chain binding approach and keep my `InputSelect` directly inside the EditForm component then this problem does not happen. It happens only in the parent-child way of coding (chain binding).

How can i correct this things?

Comment: You can use `<InputSelect @onblur="(async (e) => { editContext.Validate();})">`,With your own SelectCommon component,it cannot add `@onblur`.

Comment: what is editContext ?

Comment: you can create `public EditContext editContext{get;set;}` in the parent page.and validate it in InputSelect @onblur

Comment: Read [Your control inside an EditForm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933827/842935) section.

Comment: @daniherrera they are inside editform.

Comment: @yogihosting, your InputSelect is binded to a field that is not a property of the form EditContext model. I suggest to you to move to a simple select (not an InputSelect) and follow "Option 1" steps of my previously linked answer. Blazor is an open source project, if you take a look to validations ( [aspnetcore/src/Components/Forms/src/](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components/Forms/src) and [InputBase.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs) ) you will understand the internals of EditContext.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @dani-herrera

ApplicationUserDropDown.razor (child component):

```
    <TelerikComboBox id="userbox" @bind-Value="@Value"
             Data="@Data" TItem="UserListVM"
             TValue="Guid?" Placeholder="Select User"
             ValueField="Id" TextField="FullName">
```

ApplicationUserDropDown.razor.cs (child component):

```
public partial class ApplicationUserDropDown
{
    #region Value two way binding
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext EditContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<Guid?>> ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private Guid? _valueId;
    [Parameter]
    public Guid? Value
    {
        get => _valueId;
        set
        {
            if (_valueId == value) return;
            _valueId = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            var fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
            EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
        }
    }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Guid?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    #endregion Value two way binding
```

razor page using child component:

```
<ApplicationUserDropDown @bind-Value="Account.OwnerId"></ApplicationUserDropDown>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Account.OwnerId)">Owner is Required</ValidationMessage>
```