# Blazor Child to Parent EventCallback<List<string>> not triggering

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a shared component for a multi-select dropdown in Blazor server-side. SelectMultiple.razor child component is not passing selected values back to the parent index.razor page. EventCallback<List> SelectedItemChanged in child component doesn't seem to be triggering. Can anyone help me out please?

Below is SelectMultiple.razor

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group mb-1">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light"
                @onclick="@ToggleSelectMultiple"
                title="@SelectedItemsText">
            @ButtonText
        </button>
    </div>
    <div hidden="@toggleSelectBox" class="border border-secondary rounded py-1">
        <div class="mx-1">
            <input class="form-control" @bind="FilterText" @bind:event="oninput" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mt-1">
            @foreach (var item in FilteredItems)
            {
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="mr-1" checked="@item.IsSelected"
                           @onchange="_e => { FilteredItemChanged(item.Item, _e.Value); }" />@item.Item
                    </label><br />
                }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code{    
    //public class SelectedItem
    //{
    //    public string Item { get; set; }
    //    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    //}

    private string _filterText;
    private bool toggleSelectBox = true;
    private List<string> _selectedItems;

    [Parameter] public List<string> Elements { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> SelectedItems
    {
        get => _selectedItems;
        set
        {
            _selectedItems = value;
            SelectedItemChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedItems);
        }
    }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>> SelectedItemChanged { get; set; }

    public List<SelectedItem> FilteredItems { get; set; } = new();
    public string FilterText
    {
        get { return _filterText; }
        set
        {
            _filterText = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilterText))
            {
                FilteredItems = Elements.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(FilterText))
                    .Select(x => new SelectedItem() { Item = x, IsSelected = SelectedItems.Contains(x) }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                FilteredItems = Elements.Select(x => new SelectedItem() { Item = x, IsSelected = SelectedItems.Contains(x) }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    public string SelectedItemsText { get; set; }
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Nothing selected";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Elements.ForEach(x => FilteredItems.Add(new SelectedItem() { Item = x }));
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public void FilteredItemChanged(string item, object checkedValue)
    {
        if ((bool)checkedValue)
        {
            SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedItems.Remove(item);
        }

        SelectedItemsText = SelectedItems.Any() ? string.Join(",", SelectedItems.Select(x => x)) : null;
        ButtonText = SelectedItems.Any()
            ? (SelectedItems.Count == 1 ? SelectedItemsText : $"{SelectedItems.Count} items selected")
            : "Nothing selected";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void ToggleSelectMultiple()
    {
        toggleSelectBox = !toggleSelectBox;
        ClearSearchText();
    }

    private void ClearSearchText() => FilterText = null;
}
```

Here's my index.razor

```
@page "/"
<SelectMultiple Elements="Elements" SelectedItems="SelectedElements" SelectedItemChanged="SelectionChanged" />

<p>@SelectionAsText</p>
@code{
    public List<string> Elements { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "dog", "cat", "mouse", "hippo", "rat", "giraffe" };
    public List<string> SelectedElements { get; set; } = new();
    private string SelectionAsText;

    public void SelectionChanged()
    {
        SelectionAsText = string.Join(",", SelectedElements);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you raise the event only when the `List<string>` variable changes, which in your code happens only once, during component's initialisation.

The source of confusion is that, during the entire component's lifetime, this `List` variable points to the same object, so it doesn't *change*. The contents of that list changes, yes, but not the reference to the `List` itself.

As a starting point, I recommend to add the `InvokeAsync()` to the `FilteredItemChanged()` function. You can figure out the rest from here.

This [docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding) explains the basics around parameter binding in Blazor. Also, check the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57932850), they might be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I notice in debugging that the event is only triggered once, during initialisation. Is there away to InvokeAsync() when List is changed? Is there a better way to  get SelectedItems from child component?

Comment: @harry777, updated the answer with links to docs. It is unclear to me what exactly is a problem for you here. You don't know how to move the `InvokeAsync()` call from one place in your code to another?..

Comment: I tried that yesterday evening but it didn't (had a long day yesterday). But, I gave it a go again just now and all is working great. Thanks a lot.