# RadzenSlider - passing in callback - name vs lambda

Tags: c#, blazor, radzen

## Component `SliderButtonAlt`

Here's a component that I have in `Shared\SliderButtonAlt.razor`:

```
@code {
    private decimal _value;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<decimal> ValChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public decimal Val 
    {
        get => _value;

        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;

            _value = value;

            ValChanged.InvokeAsync(value);   
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public Action<decimal> ChangeProc { get; set; }
}

<RadzenSlider Style="width: 50%;" @bind-Value="@Val" TValue="decimal" Min="0" Max="100" Change=@(arg => ChangeProc(arg)) /> wierd

<br />

<RadzenSlider Style="width: 50%;" @bind-Value="@Val" TValue="decimal" Min="0" Max="100" Change="ChangeProc" /> works

<br />

<button>@Val</button>
```

Note that it uses the following slider component from Radzen:

https://blazor.radzen.com/slider

## Calling the component

In my `Index.razor` I have the following which calls the component:

```
@code {
    private decimal abc = 0;
    private decimal bcd = 0;

    void AbcChanged(decimal val)
    {
        bcd = abc;
    }
}

abc: @abc
bcd: @bcd

<br />

<SliderButtonAlt @bind-Val="@abc" ChangeProc="@(arg => bcd = abc)"/>
```

## Screenshot

When run, it looks like this:

[image]

## Works slider

If you drag the slider that is labeled `works`, everything works as expected.

## Weird slider

Weird slider has strange behavior:

- If you drag to the max, `abc` is set to 100 (expected) but `bcd` is not.
- If you drag to the min, `abc` is set to 0 (expected) but `bcd` is not.
- If you click arbitrary position, `abc` is updated as expected but `bcd` get the previous value of `abc`.

Max:

[image]

Min:

[image]

Arbitrary click:

[image]

## Code differences

Here are the two sliders for comparison:

```
<RadzenSlider Style="width: 50%;" @bind-Value="@Val" TValue="decimal" Min="0" Max="100" Change=@(arg => ChangeProc(arg)) /> wierd
<RadzenSlider Style="width: 50%;" @bind-Value="@Val" TValue="decimal" Min="0" Max="100" Change="ChangeProc" /> works
```

Note that the only difference is that the wierd slider uses:

```
Change=@(arg => ChangeProc(arg))
```

while the works slider uses:

```
Change="ChangeProc"
```

## Question

Why is there a difference in behavior between the weird case (lambda) and the works case (reference by name).

## Fiddle

I would have liked to provide a Blazor fiddle for this example however I'm not sure of a fiddle site that supports the `Radzen` package. If you know of one, let me know and I'll update the question.

Comment: @enet Thank you for taking a look. I was able to solve the issue. See answer below. Basically, using `EventCallback` instead of `Action` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you propose to answer your question, you should at least provide a minimal explanation to the bewildered.

Changing the `Action` delegate to EventCallback 'delegate' solve the issue indeed. After all, this is the expected type of the value that need be assigned to the RadzenSlider component's Change attribute.

But why does the slider with the Change attribute assigned with the Action delegate's name works fine, while the one with a lambda expression does not. Can you answer this.

Incidentally, you could do something like this with the Action delegate, and it would work:

```
<SliderButtonAlt @bind-Val="@abc" ChangeProc="@(arg=> { bcd = abc; StateHasChanged(); })" />
```

Contemplate on why it should work...

Incidentally, you should not modify the values of parameter properties in your app. You should not do something like this:

```
   set
   {
      // .....
        _value = value;

      //... 
   }
```

parameter properties are the way Blazor passes values from one component to another, and you must not alter their values. If you need to manipulate thier values, you should create a local copy for them. Parameter properties
should be treated as DTO. If you fail to adhere to this, you may incur very suble errors you'll never be able to discern.

This is not an answer... It is kind of a comment, which I'll delete later on. You've failed to accept a previous answer of mine (Factoring out markup in Blazor) which I've removed as I love collecting accepted answers. Therefore, I did not want to offer an answer for this question, but then it is something intriguing and I could not help offering this comment.

Comment: Your answer on the other question was a good one. However, there were two answers on the question. In cases like this I will sometimes wait for "the dust to settle" to see if more answers come in or change. Both answers were very similar. Also keep in mind that folks using this site sometimes take time to get back and interact with the responses.

Comment: Regarding your comment on `value = _value`, one of the highest rated answers here suggests just this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932850/how-to-make-two-way-binding-on-blazor-component

Comment: @dharmatech: `Both answers were very similar.` I completely disagree with you... Go back to the my answer (I've undeleted it) and see the difference.  `one of the highest rated answers here suggests just this.` To tell you the truth, I've learned Blazor from Github only; certainly not from Stackoverflow. Here's what Steve Sanderson, the creator of Blazor, says about modifying parameter values: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26230

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for the reference to the Sanderson quote.

Comment: Is there an answer here or documentation somewhere that explains how to implement a component like this without using `value = _value`? I'd be happy to add an answer here which demonstrates the recommended practice.

Comment: I've accepted both answers as they provide excellent information. I hope you leave them up. 

Comment: I've saved the text of both answers because they are so informative. I understand if you decide to delete them. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Regarding you note about using `StateHasChanged()` explicitly, I've since learned that when you use `EventCallback`, blazor calls this method for you. 

Comment: I had some more time to dig into that issue from Sanderson. Wow... that's a very clear message from him! Thank you again for pointing it out.

Comment: Hmm... Here's a link to Radzen's implementation of `RadzenSlider`. They use the `_value = value` technique. Would you say what they're doing there is not recommended? [link](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/master/Radzen.Blazor/RadzenSlider.razor.cs#L234-L240)

Comment: @dharmatech, no I won't say that "what they're doing there is not recommended." I'd say it is a bad practice. Steve Sanderson has already said that developers think it looks good, why not to use it like this. I'm sure that when that code was written for the first time, the developers were not aware of the issues with modifying [Parameter] properties. And currently they don't care. This is like using a Model in your form instead of using a ViewModel, effectively allowing hackers to set properties that should not be set by an unauthorised user.

Comment: But alas, many do not follow this recommandation to use ViewModels instead of Models... It requires more work... I provided you with a link to Steve Sanerson's input about this. Please, read the complete thread and linked posts, and decide for yourself. For me, Steve Sanderson is the authority...

Comment: So I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200814/components-with-two-way-binding-modifying-parameters) to focus on this particular issue. I've also submitted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73206088/268581) that avoids using the parameter setter to change the value. What do you think about that approach?

Answer (score 1):

In `SliderButtonAlt.razor`, change

```
[Parameter] public Action<decimal> ChangeProc { get; set; }
```

to:

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<decimal> ChangeProc { get; set; }
```

Then change the weird slider as follows:

```
<RadzenSlider Style="width: 50%;" @bind-Value="@Val" TValue="decimal"
    Min="0" Max="100" 
    Change=@(arg => ChangeProc.InvokeAsync(arg)) /> weird
```