# Blazor validation on not-built in component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a custom dropdown component (not-built in component), how could I use the custom validation in this component? no warning border is added when not valid, but validation message is working.

Answer (score 0):

No warning border is added because your custom dropdown probably doesn't inherit `InputBase`. Inherit `InputBase`, implement `TryParseValueFromString` and add the inherited `@CssClass` parameter to the desired warning border element.

I have a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734223/591285) on how to implement `InputBase`.

Comment: why should inherit InputBase, I mean, it is a dropdown, it is possible to create a new DropdownBase?

Comment: @rpozuelo20 `ItemBase<T>` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputbase-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is used for *Checkbox, Date, Number, Radio, **Select*** . Here is an example of what you want to; https://www.yogihosting.com/blazor-select-custom-validator/

Although the author leaves out that you can use `CssClass` to get the warning borders when validation is failed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputbase-1.cssclass?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-components-forms-inputbase-1-cssclass