# How to pass @binding-value to component on blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I created this component. file name: InputTextComponent.razor

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@Value"/>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

in the page index.razor

```
@page "/"

<EditForm model="@data" OnValidSubmit="()=>OnClickBtn()">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <InputTextComponent Value="data.Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
        <button type="button" >Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
       
    </div>
</EditForm>
@code{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    private Item data { get; set; } = new Item(){ Name="John"};
    private void OnClickBtn()
    {
        string k = "";
    }
}
```

When I run, it show :

then i edit the name field. and press  "ok" button.

[image]

How to pass @bind-value into component. (the same InputText on blazor component).
Thanks all!!

Comment: Didn't get your point. Where do you want to pass input value?

Comment: Parameters in Blazor are not passed by reference, meaning it won't change whatever you pass in from the parent. You need to implement an OnChange event inside your `InputTextComponent` that calls back to the parent component

Comment: Marking a perfectly good answer by @Axekan as not helpful won't win you friends!  He has interpreted the question in the same way as me.  Perhaps you haven't explained yourself well enough?

Comment: For those going down the rabbit hole. Check out this duplicate that has a really great answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932850/how-to-make-two-way-binding-on-blazor-component

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you can manually implement the Change event in your child component `InputTextComponent`. The parameter is called `Value`, so you would need to implement an EventCallback with the name `ValueChanged`.

Your `InputTextComponent` would need to look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <InputText @oninput="updateParent" @bind-Value="@Value"/>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    async void updateParent(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And then you can use @bind-Value in the parent component like `<InputTextComponent @bind-Value="data.Name"/>`

[Here is a blazor repl](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wQPkQCkj15gLPIl950) showing the full thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

I've added a bit of functionality to show you how to build out a classic Bootstrap control.

```cs
@inherits InputText

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">@this.Label</label>
    @inputControl
    <div class="form-text">@this.Commentary</div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Commentary { get; set; }

    // Gets the underlying Renderfragment built by InputText
    private RenderFragment inputControl => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

And a demo page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Test Page</h1>

<EditForm Model=this.model>
    <MyInputText class="form-control" Label="Value" Commentary="Enter a value" @bind-Value=model.Value />
</EditForm>

<div class="alert alert-info mt-3">
    Value : @model.Value
</div>

@code {
    private ModelData model = new();

    public class ModelData {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As the other answer showed binding to `oninput` you can implement that like this.  The above component would then inherit from `BlazrInputText`.

```cs
public class BlazrInputText : InputText
{
    [Parameter] public bool BindOnInput { get; set; } = true;

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.CssClass))
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);

        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValueAsString));

        if (BindOnInput)
            builder.AddAttribute(4, "oninput", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
        else
            builder.AddAttribute(5, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));

        builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(6, __inputReference => Element = __inputReference);
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem.  If this is your accepted answer tick it.  Other people won't then think that you are still waiting for an answer.