# @bind-Value in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, binding, blazor, blazor-webassembly, two-way-binding

I'm trying to use nested two-way binding in Blazor, and I'm running into an issue where I need to bind an InputText value to a prop of an object.
I have a model I pass to a custom form component and then to a single custom input text  based on the prop type:

**Index page**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
    <FormSection Forecast=@forecast />
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" @onclick=SaveData>Save data</button>
</div>
```

**FormComponent**

```
<div>
    <label for="datetime" class="form-label">Date</label>
    <InputDateCustom TextValue="@Forecast.Date" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="temperature" class="form-label">Temperature</label>
    <InputNumberCustom TextValue="@Forecast.TemperatureC" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="summary" class="form-label">Summary</label>
    <InputTextCustom TextValue="@Forecast.Summary" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public WeatherForecast Forecast { get; set; }
}
```

**Input date**

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" @bind-value=TextValue />

@code {
    [Parameter] public DateTime TextValue { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

**Input text**

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" @bind-value=TextValue />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string TextValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**Input number**

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" @bind-value=TextValue />

@code {
    [Parameter] public int TextValue { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

With this structure, when I save data with the button in the Index page there are no data in the model.
If I use @bind-Value in the form component when I pass the value inside the input component (@bind-Value=Forecast.Date instead of TextValue="@Forecast.Date"), I get the error: **Object of type 'TestProject.Client.Components.InputTextCustom' does not have a property matching the name 'TextValueChanged'**

Instead, using the input components directly in the form component, it works and I see the values in the model.

What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to use two-way binding with nested components?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932850/how-to-make-two-way-binding-on-blazor-component

Comment: I think I solved creating an EventCallback<string> in the child and an EventCallback<WeatherForecast> in the parent. 
The first one is invoked by the @onchange method of the input field, the second one is invoked after setting the value of the view model.

Comment: @MirkoPutignani - I doubt you solved it that way, [Polite] and it's possibly a kludge if you have. I won't provide an answer until you confirm you still want one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your implementation.

If you use `input`, you need to use `bind`, not `bind-Value`.

So your `InputTextCustom` needs to look like this:

```cs
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" @bind:get="Value" @bind:set="this.HasChanged"  />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private Task HasChanged(string value)
    {
        return this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And your `FormComponent` looks like this:

```cs
//...
<div>
    <label for="summary" class="form-label">Summary</label>
    <InputTextCustom @bind-Value="@Forecast.Summary" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public WeatherForecast Forecast { get; set; } = new();
}
```

My form then looks like this:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<FormComponent Forecast="_forecast" />
<div class="m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Save">Save</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Summary: @_forecast.Summary</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast _forecast = new();

    private void Save()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't display the current value of Summary, although the state is correct.  There's no built in mechanism for parents to see state changes in shared objects.  How you handle this depends on your context.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to Inherit from InputBase

Comment: You're possibly right, but need to explain a little more [not me who marked this down].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).