# Passing parameter from Parent To child Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to pass parameter from the parent to the child component I know that there is a solution
which is Cascading parameter but in my situation the child component share some functionality with the parent component so I apply inheritance in this case do i still need to use cascading parameter
the main question which is better?

```
  private ApiResource Api { get; set; } = new ApiResource();
        [CascadingParameter] public int ApiId { get; set; }
        private async Task Save()
        {
            var saveTask =  _apiResource.UpdateApiResource(Api);
            var logActionTask = LogAction(ApiManagementLogDescription.UpdateApi.ToDescriptionString());
            await Task.WhenAll(saveTask, logActionTask);
        }
        private async Task<ServiceResponse<ApiResource>> FetchData() => 
             await _apiResource.GetApiResourceById(ApiId);
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var apiResponse = await FetchData();

            if (!apiResponse.Success)
            {
                SnackBar.HuiAdd(apiResponse.Message, "Warning", "Warning", Severity.Warning);
            }
            Api = apiResponse.Result;
        }
```

Comment: Yes.  But you only need to declare the `CascadingParameter` in the child.  Who is doing the cascade and how?

Comment: you mean 2 way param? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933827/18795180